# How can I see which variable or functions are running in CPU tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a CNN in tensorflow. I am using tf.device(/gpu:0) to put all of my variables in gpu, but it seems that some of them are still in cpu. I am looking at my gpu utils when I am running my code, it goes up to 100% and then goes down to 0%.

I know that if I use config.log_device_placement = True I can see which variable are assigned to which device. but because the number of variable are a lot in my code, I couldn't find out which one are in cpu.

So, is there any way that I just see which variables are pinned to cpu? 
Or, do you have any idea why some of my variable should be pinned to cpu while I am using tf.device to assign them to gpu?

By the way, after I changed upsampler (simple interpolator tf.image.resize_images) by following code for upsampling this issue happened:

```
def unravel_argmax(argmax, shape):
    with tf.device(gpu_n):
        argmax_shape = argmax.get_shape()
        new_1dim_shape = tf.shape(tf.constant(0, shape=[tf.Dimension(4), argmax_shape[0]*argmax_shape[1]*argmax_shape[2]*argmax_shape[3]]))
        batch_shape = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64, shape=[argmax_shape[0], 1, 1, 1]).get_shape()
        b = tf.multiply(tf.ones_like(argmax), tf.reshape(tf.range(shape[0]), batch_shape))
        y = argmax // (shape[2] * shape[3])
        x = argmax % (shape[2] * shape[3]) // shape[3]
        c = tf.ones_like(argmax) * tf.range(shape[3])
        pack = tf.stack([b, y, x, c])
        pack = tf.reshape(pack, new_1dim_shape)
        pack = tf.transpose(pack)
        return pack


def unpool_layer2x2_batch(updates, mask, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1]):
    with tf.device(gpu_n):
        input_shape = updates.get_shape()
        new_dim_y = input_shape[1] * ksize[1]
        new_dim_x = input_shape[2] * ksize[2]
        output_shape = tf.to_int64((tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64, shape=[input_shape[0], new_dim_y, new_dim_x, input_shape[3]]).get_shape()))
        indices = unravel_argmax(mask, output_shape)
        new_1dim_shape = tf.shape(tf.constant(0, shape=[input_shape[0] * input_shape[1] * input_shape[2] * input_shape[3]]))
        values = tf.reshape(updates, new_1dim_shape)
        ret = tf.scatter_nd(indices, values, output_shape)
        return ret
```

I got this code from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2169) for unpooling.

Comment: Do you actually have any evidence that some ops are being computed by the CPU?

Comment: That's my question! How can I find out if some of my variable are pinned in cpu? currently, when I am looking at my gpu utils, it seems that some of the variable are on CPU, because it goes up and down (between 100% and 0%). It seems some of variable are passing between cpu  and gpu.

Comment: A more common problem is that some in the middle of computation is placed on cpu. Also it's possible that your GPU is waiting for data to be read/input into TF. You can figure this out by looking at timelines

Comment: Yes, I think some variable in the middle is placed on cpu and I wanna know how can I understand which ones are placed in cpu? I am sure it is not because of reading inputs to TF.

Comment: Use a Timeline. All the information required is easily googlable.

Comment: Unfortunately, because there are many nodes in my network and execution time for some of them are large, the information from Timeline couldn't help me.

Comment: I just run that piece of code and I figured out that tf.mod, tf.floor operations can not be run in GPU. So, in the middle of network they are passed to CPU and it causes problem. By the way, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can log device placement via configuration of Session. Setting:

```
  sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```